# Checking if value from one column is in multiple other columns

Tags: qgis, expression, rule

How do you write an expression for a style rule that will check if the value from column A exists in columns B, C, D & E?

I have a polygon layer that I would like to flag with a style depending on whether the values from column 'MH#' are found in any of the 'MH1-MH4' columns.

**Example:**

```
record 39: MH# 883031 is found in the MH2 column of record 38, I'll make it red.

record 42: MH# 883777 is found in the MH1 column of record 37, I'll make it red.

record 37: MH# 882516 is not found in any of the MH1-MH4 columns, I'll make it yellow.
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN array_contains(array_distinct(array_agg("MH1")), "MH#")  
       OR array_contains(array_distinct(array_agg("MH2")), "MH#")
THEN color_rgb(255,0,0)
ELSE color_rgb(255,255,0)
END
```

[image]

Comment: This check only for the MH1 and MH2 column (but it's just a matter of adding two more OR line for the two other column if you want to check the four column)

Comment: That's just what I was looking for, thank you for the very useful answer.